# Calculate $\int_{S^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2}}dS$ where $a^2+b^2+c^2<1$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $a^2+b^2+c^2 < 1$ and $S^2$ be unit sphere in $R^3$. Calculate $$\int_{S^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2}}dS$$

Let $(x,y,z)=(\cos\theta \cos\phi,\cos\theta \sin\phi, \sin\theta)$. By definition,
$$\int_{S^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2}}dS\\
=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\cos\theta \cos\phi-a)^2+(\cos\theta \sin\phi-b)^2+(\sin\theta-c)^2}}\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$$

It is too complicate.
This is calculus exam problem that I took yesterday.  Is there any good idea?

Comment: not sure if this helps, but there is some simplification if you set $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$. the original integral over the surface of the unit sphere is then equal to $\int_{S^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-r)^2+y^2+z^2}}dS$

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but $x=\sin\theta\cos\phi$...$z=\cos\theta$ and $y$ must be adjusted accordingly

Comment: Surely there's a geometric argument which makes the result obvious. The integrand is inverse distance to the surface, and the result is always the surface area. I can't figure out how to argue it, so maybe you can't avoid integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

taking my suggested simplification a little further, since $y^2+z^2=1-x^2$ on the surface of the sphere, we obtain:
$$
I = 2\pi \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xr+r^2}}dx
$$

Comment: How nice proof! Thanks.

Comment: i think you'll find the integral is $4\pi$ for all $r$ satisfying $|r| \le 1$

Answer (score 2):

Let $r=1,\vec{A}=(x,y,z)=r(\cos\theta \cos\phi,\cos\theta \sin\phi, \sin\theta)$ and
$r'=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}<1$, $\vec{B}=(a,b,c)=r'(\cos\theta' \cos\phi',\cos\theta' \sin\phi', \sin\theta')$, then we can expand the $\frac{1}{|\vec{A}-\vec{B}|}$ potential as:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2}}=\frac{1}{|\vec{A}-\vec{B}|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+(r')^2-2r r'\cos\gamma}}$$
$$=\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{r'^l}{r^{l+1}}P_l(\cos\gamma)\tag{1}$$

where $\gamma$ is the angle between $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$.

We can also expand the Legendre polynomial $P_l(\cos\gamma)$ in terms of spherical harmonics $Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$ as:

$$P_l(\cos\gamma)=\frac{4\pi}{2l+1}\sum_{m=-l}^{+l}Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)Y_{lm}^{*}(\theta',\phi') \tag{2}$$

Since
$$\int_{S^2}Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)dS = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)\sin\theta d\theta d\phi=2\sqrt{\pi}\delta_{l0}\delta_{m0}\tag{2}$$

and 
$$Y_{00}^{*}(\theta',\phi')=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\tag{3}$$

we obtain:
$$\int_{S^2}\frac{1}{|\vec{A}-\vec{B}|}dS = 4\pi \tag{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x,y,z)=(a+\cos\theta \cos\phi,b+\cos\theta \sin\phi,c+ \sin\theta)$
$$\int_{S^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2}}dS\\
=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\cos\theta\cos\phi)^2+(\cos\theta \sin\phi)^2+(\sin\theta)^2}}\sin\theta d\theta d\phi=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta d\phi\\=4\pi$$

Comment: $x,y,z$ are not parametrized that way.

Comment: @i707107 we can always shift the origin without affecting the integral

Comment: Shifting the origin without affecting the integral should be justified. Otherwise, your calculation is just when $a=b=c=0$.